# How to remove everything after the last white space?

Tags: php

I have values that either have one space or two spaces.

Example: Current Status [3] has two spaces while Current [22] has one space.

How would We remove everything after the second white space?

If it is easier to remove square brackets and values inside them, that would be appreciated as well.

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to simply create them without the brackets/numbers in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace() with a simple regex like

```
[ ]{2}.*
```

who find two spaces and everything behind.

example:

```
preg_replace('[ ]{2}.*', '', $string);
```

Comment: I don't mind being downvoted good people. It helps to explain why so we avoid whatever we could have done wrong.

My understanding is that if your question isn't clear or doesn't help someone else.

6 months from now, this question would have helped several as has been the case with me quite a few times here.

What is funny is that those questions that have helped me were all downvoted.

Anyway, thanks @Macbernie for your response.

Comment: Well, there are already several similar problems and their solutions in Stack-overflow.  You cannot just say "I don't mind down vote" . Of course you wont find exactly 100% same problem and the solution , rather you'll find a similar one. So just try to search around for similar problems and their solutions. After all a good programmer (or learner) can build up a full system with just few hints.

Comment: @Macbernie, I just have one follow up question.

Per the example I gave above, some of those values have one space.

Your solution is to find two spaces. 

What it only found one space?

Sorry, I am still trying to find my way around php

Comment: @Nepal12, I promise you I did. I am not well versed in php. So, at this point, it is not easy to pick up something that says white space but unrelated to my question. Besides, you could recommend closing it due to duplicate rather than downvote me. Please think about it. That we are given the power to determine someone's faith doesn't mean we abuse it.

Comment: Ok, I believe you, try this `preg_split("/(?<=\w)\b\s*/", $string);` , It'll break up every word.

Comment: let me know if it work , you can do it as, `$str = preg_split("/(?<=\w)\b\s*/", $string);` , then `$str[0] -> first word then $str[1] -> second word ....`